# Individually (not as a batch) email one message to a list of addresses held in Excel

Tags: excel, email, vbscript

I have a list of emails I need transmit (about 100) and if I send all these people one message (so I send it once to 100 people) it will end up in their spam folder. Since it is quite important that it doesn't, I had the idea of making a program in VBScript that `tabs` and `alt+tabs` between the Excel sheet and the email program to `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`. The problem is, the `alt+tab` (`wshshell.sendkeys "%+{TAB}"`) just makes the selected window lose focus, and doesn't select another window.

I would like to know whether there is a program/way to program that sends emails separately, to different people but the same email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mail merge function in MS Word. There you create your E-Mail, add an Excel-list and can use the fields from the list to fill fields in your E-Mail. So you can personaliize the eMails. They will be sent separately through Outlook then.

Here's a very easy description in form of a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ylYITE0ayU